# ASP.NET 2.0 web site gets ThreadAbortException

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, multithreading, timeout

We're running a web service as a web site project.  Clients make requests which return after a few seconds, but which spawn a thread that should run for hours.  The thread makes web requests and writes to a database, and is throttled with `Thread.Sleep` calls.

After running for about 20 minutes with several threads running, all the threads receive a `ThreadAbortException` at the same time.  Thread.resetAbort doesn't help.  The exception can occur during a SQL call, during a web request or during a `Thread.Sleep`.

I thought the problem might be the `httpRuntime` attribute `executionTimeout` in web.config, but that didn't solve the issue.

Any other ideas what might be killing off all our threads?

Comment: Did you look at your session timeout? I'm guessing that these threads are owned by a session rather than the app, and as such may be subject to that timeout.

Comment: Good thought, but we're not using the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application pool in IIS has an idle time-out.  It needed to be turned off.

(Administrative Tools > IIS.  Right-click the application pool > properties.  Performance tab.)

Answer (score 3):

I would guess that the web application owns the thread, and the application shuts down after a period of time.

If I were architecting something like this,  I would write a web services which takes yourp your clients requests and puts them in a database, then I'd write a windows service that polls that database for client requests and spawns the threads which do whatever it is you need (makes web requests and write to a database).  It sounds like your writing some sort of processor engine, and I don't think an asp.net app is a good place to host that kind of thing.

Comment: Agreed.  I don't control the architecture on this project, but these kinds of problems are good fuel for that argument.